# ASP.NET Application not authenticating using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, windows-authentication, http-status-code-401

I have a Win2003 Server running a number of different ASP.NET websites, all using mixed mode authentication.

One of the applications is causing me issues from one laptop, I get a pile of 401's when I try to navigate to it - ending in a generic "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error.  From a different PC I can navigate to the application just fine and I am correctly authenticated.

I am using IE on XP and versions 6-8 had the same issue.

Once in a blue moon, I can get into the application from my laptop.

This problem also affects one or two other people too.

Note, Firefox seems to be okay with opening the application but in general Firefox is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem some time ago. It was caused by wrong password stored in credential manager. Firefox most likely does not use it. Try check:

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Open User Accounts.
3. Click Manage My Network Passwords.

Comment: Hmm.. Well that is handy. Except it only to server domain level.  Other applications on the same server authenticate me just fine.